# Navbar using anchor links and "position sticky" positions page at different locations on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css

Here is what i have so far. It will show link target "CONTACT INFO" just beneath navbar on Firefox developer edition and on mobile chrome.
And stops target under navbar on Edge and Chrome.
Not shure why there is different placements and what the correct placement is. Is there something missing in my code?

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-image: url("img/topography.svg"), linear-gradient(110deg, #4a95c5, darkgrey);
  /*Old Color: #0f83ca*/
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.maindiv {
  min-height: 200vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: [start] minmax(max-content, 1fr) [content-start] minmax(70vw, 70vw) [content-end] minmax(max-content, 1fr) [end];
  grid-template-rows: minmax(200px, min-content) minmax(20px, max-content) minmax(80vh, auto) minmax(150vh, auto) minmax(100px, min-content);
}

.logo {
  z-index: 0;
  grid-column: start / end;
  background-image: url("img/waves.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0, 0, 0, 0;
  /*border: 1px solid #000000;*/
}


/*Menubar*/

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: start / end;
  background-color: #0f83ca;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  /*font-size: 0.5em; */
}

.menu {
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.knapp {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  grid-template: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.knapp:hover,
.active {
  background-color: #0f83ca;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
}

.knapp:hover::after,
.active::after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #25b6de;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.bodydiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: inherit;
  padding-top: 40px;
  justify-self: center;
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
}

.bodydiv_under {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: inherit;
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600/?fishing");
  background-size: cover;
}

.body2div {
  justify-self: center;
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
}

.paragraph3 {
  /*padding-top: 60px;*/
}

.footer {
  grid-column: start / end;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <header class="header" id="wrapper">
    <ul class="menu" id="myDIV">
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp1 active">HOME</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp2">APARTMENT</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp3">GALLERY</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp4">SEA MAP</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#example">
        <li class="knapp knapp5">FISHING GEAR</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#example">
        <li class="knapp knapp5">CONTACT</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="bodydiv">
    <p class="paragraph2">
      <div class="bodydiv_under"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body2div">
    <a id="example">
      <p class="paragraph3" id="block">CONTACT INFO:</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="paragraph4">Her kommer en footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Can be observed here:
https://codepen.io/rjan-sk-r/pen/zQqMxb

Answer (score 0):

It's basically because how inline `<a>` tag is rendered in each browser is different. Those browsers seem to have different default `line-height` values which affect `<a id="example">...</a>` element's height differently.

As a quick solution, I applied `display: block` in `a#example {..}` CSS rules. And I also added `padding-top: 70px` to make the text not to slide under the menu. Try below and see if it works:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-image: url("img/topography.svg"), linear-gradient(110deg, #4a95c5, darkgrey);
  /*Old Color: #0f83ca*/
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.maindiv {
  min-height: 200vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: [start] minmax(max-content, 1fr) [content-start] minmax(70vw, 70vw) [content-end] minmax(max-content, 1fr) [end];
  grid-template-rows: minmax(200px, min-content) minmax(20px, max-content) minmax(80vh, auto) minmax(150vh, auto) minmax(100px, min-content);
}

.logo {
  z-index: 0;
  grid-column: start / end;
  background-image: url("img/waves.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0, 0, 0, 0;
  /*border: 1px solid #000000;*/
}


/*Menubar*/

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: start / end;
  background-color: #0f83ca;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  /*font-size: 0.5em; */
}

.menu {
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a#example {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 70px
}

.knapp {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  grid-template: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.knapp:hover,
.active {
  background-color: #0f83ca;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
}

.knapp:hover::after,
.active::after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #25b6de;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.bodydiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: inherit;
  padding-top: 40px;
  justify-self: center;
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
}

.bodydiv_under {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: inherit;
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600/?fishing");
  background-size: cover;
}

.body2div {
  justify-self: center;
  grid-column: content-start / content-end;
}

.paragraph3 {
  /*padding-top: 60px;*/
}

.footer {
  grid-column: start / end;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <header class="header" id="wrapper">
    <ul class="menu" id="myDIV">
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp1 active">HOME</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp2">APARTMENT</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp3">GALLERY</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li class="knapp knapp4">SEA MAP</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#example">
        <li class="knapp knapp5">FISHING GEAR</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#example">
        <li class="knapp knapp5">CONTACT</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="bodydiv">
    <p class="paragraph2">
      <div class="bodydiv_under"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body2div">
    <a id="example">
      <p class="paragraph3" id="block">CONTACT INFO:</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="paragraph4">Her kommer en footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what the issue was. I've learned something today. Thumbs up!

Comment: @ØrjanSkår awesome, happy to be able to help! Could you vote/select my answer if it worked? Thanks and good luck!